# mobile devices cannot connect to LAN server via hostname

Tags: mobile, hostname, lan

I have setup a lan with a router, with a few computers connected via both wifi and cables. There are also mobile devices connected to the network.

I have a server running on one of the computers. Other computers can access the server via its hostname (http://myserver:8080/), but mobile devices are not able to.

Is there any softwares or any means I can get the mobile devices to access via server hostname too?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to setup a Name Server (DNS probably) on a computer in your local network. This Name Server should be able to resolve hostnames to IPs (e.g. myserver to 10.0.0.21). Configure your mobile devices so that they use this DNS to resolve device names.

Comment: i am trying to setup dns on windows xp/7 now. do you recommend any real-easy-to-use software? also, how do i configure the mobile devices to use DNS??

Comment: You may try Simple DNS Plus. Other software mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DNS_server_software). For settings on mobile device, each phone has its own menu and interface to set DNS. Note, some feature phones may not allow you to change network settings. Smart phones do allow changes in IP and DNS settings.